# jquery dynamic url

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form and the url for submitting the form will generated dynamicly

```
var Var1 = new Array();
var Var2 = new Array();
if(Var1.length === 0)
$(this).attr('action', 'http://localhost/Method' ).submit();
if(Var1.length != 0 && Var2.length === 0)
$(this).attr('action', 'http://localhost/Method/Var1').submit();
if(Var1.length != 0 && Var2.length != 0)
$(this).attr('action', 'http://localhost/Method/Var1/Var2').submit();
```

and all that URLs fires one method in the server and it is

```
public function Method(){}
public function Method(Var1){}
public function Method(Var1 , Var2){}
```

is there anyway to make all the last 3 methods as one method? something like this:

```
public function Method(Var1, Var2){
    if(  condition for Var1 ){// doSomthing}
    if(  condition for Var2 ){// doSomthing}
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, we shouldn't do it for you.

Comment: @gdoron I am talking about the PHP end. is he using any PHP framework?

Comment: i am using php , and i wrote it , but someone edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need this function for PHP, you can use [`func_get_arg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) and [`func_num_args`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php):

```php
public function Method() {
    $numArguments = func_num_args();

    if ($numArguments >= 1) {
        $argument1 = func_get_arg(0);
        // Do something with argument 1
    }

    if ($numArguments >= 2) {
        $argument2 = func_get_arg(1);
        // Do something with argument 2
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you but your code will make an error if there is just 1 argumet , code argument2 will be undifiend

Comment: @LinCR Actually `func_get_arg` returns `false` if the argument doesn't exist, hence the two tests checking if the arguments exist or not.

Comment: i got this error `Notice: Undefined offset: 0` but my method is `Method(var1, var2)`

Comment: @LinCR I've changed the function to use `func_num_args` to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 2):

If all the three url calls a single method in your server you can **use the [default argument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) mechanism**.

```
public function Method($Var1=null, $Var2=null){
    if(is_null($Var1)){// doSomthing}
    if(is_null($Var2)){// doSomthing}
}
```

Obviously to map these urls you need to use some sorts of router logic. And the router must dispatch the proper method of the object.

For exmaple if your url is something like `/index.php/Object/method/param1/param2`, `index.php` should create the proper object first.

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQEUST_URI']);
array_shift($parts); // emtpy part
array_shift($parts); // index.php
$cls = array_shift($parts) // Object
$obj = new $cls;
```

And then dispatch the method.

```
$method = array_shift($parts);
call_user_func_array(array($obj, $method), $parts);
```

Comment: OMG , i didn't understant what you worte , because i am new to PHP and new to jQuery , i upvote your answer , really thank you for help , and sorry cos i didn't understant ur work , my english is even bad to , really thank you

Comment: Its important that you understand my code. because almost same code is running on your web app.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function Method(){
      $root = 'http://localhost/Method/',
      $Var1 = func_get_args(0) || '',
      $Var2 = func_get_args(1) || '';

  if($Var1 && $Var2) $root .= $Var1  + '/' + $Var2;
  else if($Var1 && !$Var2) $root .= '/' + $Var1;
}
```

Comment: thank you dear, you are always helping me , but this time i was asking about the function on the server , not on my jQuery

Comment: That PHP isn't even valid... you don't define variables with `var`, nor do you define variables without `$`. The `||` trick also doesn't work in PHP, and you can't `+` strings together as you have above.

Comment: sorry  , other answer helps me more , really sorry , i am sosryr, and realy very very thank you man